# How to fix no sound issue for mkv video in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, video, video-streaming

I have a video file in MKV format, i want to play that file in the browser without converting, how can i play this file format in browser?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mkv" type="video/mkv" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

when I use this, I can't hear sound.
I can see issue for .mkv format video.
.mp4 format is fine.

who can help me about this issue?

Comment: You need to... **(1)** Find out the codecs inside the MKV **(2)** Then check if the browser supports them **(3)** Then read the MKV bytes to extract the audio/video data and play it via MediaSource Extensions (playback setup will depend on the a/v codecs inside the MKV). I don't know how much of that you can handle but there's resources on Google search for all the above, eg: tools for checking codecs, articles for understanding MKV byte structure. I recommend a **hex editor** to preview the bytes you are writing code to find, if you _"Want to play MKV file in the browser without converting"_